# Отложенные битые held пакеты

Tags: ubuntu, apt-get, wireshark

Набившая оскомину, но каждый раз разная проблема - held пакеты.

Это вывод apt-get

```
Пакеты, имеющие неудовлетворённые зависимости:  wireshark : Зависит:
wireshark-qt но он не будет установлен или wireshark-gtk но он не будет установлен 
E: Невозможно исправить ошибки, у вас отложены (held) битые пакеты.
```

Это вывод aptitude

```
Следующие пакеты имеют неудовлетворённые зависимости: 
 libnl-route-3-200 : Зависит: libnl-3-200 (= 3.2.21-1) но установлен
 3.2.21-1ubuntu1. Следующие действия разрешат зависимости:
 Оставить для следующих пакетов их текущие версии:
 1)     libnl-route-3-200 [Не установлен]                              
 2)     wireshark [Не установлен]                                      
 3)     wireshark-qt [Не установлен]                                   


      Оставить следующие зависимости неразрешёнными: 
4)     wireshark-common рекомендует wireshark (>=
     2.2.3+g57531cd-1~trusty1) | ts
```

В /var/lib/dpkg/status упоминаний пакетов wireshark нет. Стандартные средства вроде 'install -f' не помогли. Прошу помощи

Comment: для того, чтоб поделиться выводом команд, имеет смысл сделать этот вывод на английском, переопределив перед выполнением этих команд в текущей сессии переменную окружения: `$ export LC_ALL=C`

Answer (score 1):

узнать список «зафиксированных» (*held*, основная форма слова: *hold*) пакетов можно, например, так:

```
$ dpkg --get-selections | grep hold
```

отметить пакет «зафиксированным» можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo apt-mark hold имя-пакета
```

снять отметку «зафиксирован» можно, например, так:

```
$ sudo apt-mark unhold имя-пакета
```

Answer (score 1):

Проблема решена при помощи aptitude, извините за беспокойство. Мне и в голову не приходило, что на предложение aptitude исправить что-то можно ответить "нет".

**@alexander barakin**, в следующий раз учту, спасибо.